Getting compilation error on running a long SPARQL query on anzograph
I have installed anzograph frontend 3.1 , I am running a SELECT query with IN Filter  having (1,2,3...,1000)  values.
The query execution is failing with below error -
/opt/cambridgesemantics/anzograph/internal/code/407/4.cpp:Compilation failed Result code 1
I am running the below query:
SELECT ?s (IRI(<comp>) AS ?labels) ?attr1
  FROM <DemoGraph>
 WHERE { ?s rdf:type <comp> . OPTIONAL{?s <c_id> ?attr1 } . FILTER(?attr1 IN ("1"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "2"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "3"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "4"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "5"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "6"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "7"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "8"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "9"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "10"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "11"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "12"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "13"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              "14"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>,
                                                                              ... ,
                                                                              "1000"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int)) }

I have the following questions:

Is there a limit on number of values in IN operator  filter query in anzograph?
Is there a character limit to query execution in anzograph server and if so, then can this limit be increased?
Is there a character limit for SPARQL query  in get or post request on endpoint  execution

